# Where are and what is the status of other species in the mirror universe at the time of DS9?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-ds9, star-trek-tos, mirror-universe

In the DS9 episode: "Crossover" the federation has fallen and humans (Terrans) are slave laborers. The federation is made up of a bunch of species (Andorians, Vulcans, etc.), not just humans.

What happened to all of the other species in the federation?

Also what is the status other species like Romulans, Ferengi, etc.

Comment: BTW, that's "Terrans", not "Terans".  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earthling

Comment: Interesting question, but the fate of each species, unless they ultimately shared the same fate with one or more species, is a question unto itself.

Comment: We do see some Ferengi (Quark, Rom and Brunt) - and I'm sure that we hear about Romulans, even if we don't see them... you'll probably have to read some of the books to get more details than the series shows

Comment: To be precise, the "federation" never fell in "Crossover" because it never existed.  The Terran Empire is what fell.  The mirror universe is the same one that existed in the TOS ["Mirror, Mirror"](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Mirror,_Mirror_(episode)) and ENT ["In the Mirror](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/In_a_Mirror,_Darkly_(episode))[, Darkly"](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/In_a_Mirror,_Darkly,_Part_II_(episode)).

Comment: LMAO! Wow! To be precise, whatever you want to call the empire, Terran Empire or Federation, it's the equivalent and you know that. Further, lol, I wasn't asking for a detailed list of every known species & what happened to them. You guys are really smarter then that. This site isn't an opportunity to jump on a question to edit it, put the question on hold, or  close it. It's not a place to just shoot people down. It's just a question and answer site, it's not that serious. My question was pretty basic, if it's a mirror universe what happened to other 'prominent' species in our known universe.